# local nodeJS database parsing using JSON library in android application

Tags: java, android, json, node.js

I have created local DAtabase, with MongoDB and NODEJS, and now i want to parse databse data with my android app, i think i write java code right , but it doesn not work, please help.
Thanks

Here is my Java code.

```
package com.example.hakobm.buttonparsing;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected TextView tvData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

    new JSONTask().execute("http://localhost:3000/api/people");

}

 public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        int statusCode = 0;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect(); //connect to server


            statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();


            if (statusCode ==  200) {
                System.out.println("Server responded with code: " + statusCode);

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJSON = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("people");

                StringBuffer finalBufferdData = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject finalObj = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String peopleName = finalObj.getString("name");
                    Integer age = finalObj.getInt("age");
                    finalBufferdData.append(peopleName + "-->" + age + "\n");
                }

                return finalBufferdData.toString(); //pases result to PostExecute
            }else{
                Log.i("Hakob_log","Error");
            }

        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(connection !=null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader !=null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvData.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you testing on emulator or android phone?

Comment: i'm testing on android phone, i guess maybe it somehow connected with
this line 
 new JSONTask().execute("http://localhost:3000/api/people");
maybe it cann't understand localhost word

Comment: Yes, you are right. Use same network on phone and local machine and replace localhost with your localmachine ip-address

Comment: Ok now i will try, 
Did you check my java code, is it right?